# Angular $routeProvider with parameters in template

Tags: angularjs, parameters, route-provider

I have written 2 directives "news" and "newsItem". 
Now I want to make the routing work properly.

This code works perfectly for news, because there is no parameter needed...
But not for news-items, with parameter, that doesn't work.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/news', {
            template: '<news></news>'
        })
        .when('/news/:id', {
            template: '<news-item id=' + id + '></news-item>'
        })
})
```

Do I want it to be too easy? What should i do to make this work, without writing a controller only for routing-purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Using $routeParams should work.

Try this.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $routeParams) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/news', {
                template: '<news></news>'
            })
            .when('/news/:id', {
                template: '<news-item id=' + $routeParams.id + '></news-item>'
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example does not work because `id` does not exist in the scope of your view.

The recommended way to solve this is to add a controller that assigns the `id` state param to the scope of your view like this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/news', {
      template: '<news></news>'
    })
    .when('/news/:id', {
      template: '<news-item id="{{ id }}"></news-item>',
      controller: function($scope, $routeParams){
        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
      }
    });
});
```

I know you explicitly asked for a way without a controller but I would really not avoid a controller in this case. Using a controller is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

You could have `template` with function, basically which will have route parameter in its first argument.

**Code**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/news', {
    template: '<news></news>'
  })
    .when('/news/:id', {
    template: function(params) { //params will have route parameter.
      return '<news-item id=' + $routeParams.id + '></news-item>';
    }
  })
})
```